# Create n rows per id | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Dataframe `df` as follows:

| id | lob | addr | addr2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 001 | 1234 | 0 |
| a1 | 001 | 1233 | 0 |
| a3 | 003 | 1221 | 0 |
| a4 | 009 | 1234 | 0 |

I want to generate `n` (let's take 4) rows per id, with the other columns being `null/na/nan` values.
So, the above table is to be transformed to:

| id | lob | addr | addr2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 001 | 1234 | 0 |
| a1 | 001 | 1233 | 0 |
| a1 | 001 | na | na |
| a1 | na | na | na |
| a3 | 003 | 1221 | 0 |
| a3 | na | na | na |
| a3 | na | na | na |
| a3 | na | na | na |
| a4 | 009 | 1234 | 0 |
| a4 | na | na | na |
| a4 | na | na | na |
| a4 | na | na | na |

How can I achieve this? I will have anywhere from 500-700 ids at the time of execution and the n will always be 70 (so each id should have 70 rows).

I wanted to create a loop that would create a row, do a group by id, see if it's less than 70 and repeat the process but it would end up doing a lot of unnecessary operations.

Comment: The 3rd row for id 1 should also be na

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using Counter to count how many extra rows you need for each ID, and then just appending the new data:

```
from collections import Counter
id_count = Counter(df['id'])
# Create lists of each id repeated the number of times each is needed:
n = 4
id_values = [[i] * (n - id_count[i]) for i in id_count.keys()]
# Flatten to a single list:
id_values = [i for s in id_values for i in s]
# Create as new DataFrame and append to existing data:
new_data = pd.DataFrame({"id": id_values})
df = df.append(new_data).sort_values(by="id")
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with this approach without a problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can enumerate the rows within an `id` then, try `stack/unstack` or `pivot`:

```
(df.assign(enum=df.groupby('id').cumcount())
   .query('enum <4')
   .set_index(['enum','id'])
   .unstack('id')
   .reindex(range(4))
   .stack('id',dropna=False)
   .sort_index(level='id')
   .reset_index('id')
)
```

Comment: Hey @Quang Hoang, I appreciate your response. Your answer is throwing an Index error. My example actually contains 4 columns instead of 3 (change in requirements). When I tried to use your code I got the following error: IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12. It fails at .stack('id',dropna=False)

Comment: @Harsha the code works. when I create the df like this `df = pd.DataFrame([s.split() for s in ["a1  001  1234  0",
"a1  001  1233  0",
"a3  003  1221  0",
"a4  009  1234  0",]], columns=['id', 'lob', 'addr', 'addr2'])` The data I copy pasted from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat function in Pandas to optimize the running time, the code can looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
def replication(n, table):
        cols = [x in table.columns]
        empty_tab = table.copy()
        for x in cols:
            if x != 'ID':
                empty_tab[x] = np.nan
        for x in range(n):
                table = pd.concat([table, empty_tab.copy()], columns = cols) 
        return table
```

the second copy() is not really necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
n = [1, 2, 3]
df[_count] = ",".join(n)
df[_count] = df[_count].str.split(",")
df = df.explode("_count", ignore_index=True).drop(columns="_count")
```

`explode` is a pretty nifty method that creates multiple rows of input for a given column https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html