# Python: Expand one row into multiple rows and make calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two observations:

```
    Date    Confirmed Cases
0   2020-12-27  100
1   2020-12-28  1000
```

Out of this dataframe, I want to make this table:

```
    Date    Confirmed Cases
0   2020-12-27  100
1   2020-12-27  280
2   2020-12-27  460
3   2020-12-27  640
4   2020-12-27  820
5   2020-12-28  1000
```

Basically, I want to expand my two rows into six rows and the value for the other 4 fours rows would ascend equally to the sixth row value.

So, if my first row holds 100 value and second row - 1000, and I want to have 4 new rows added, the equal part for every row would be: `(1000 - 100) / (4 + 1)`

Here is the data:

```
pd.DataFrame({"Date": ['2020-12-27', '2020-12-28'],
             "Confirmed Cases": [100, 1000]})
```

Comment: how do you determine how many rows must be added?  Always 4?

Comment: Are there always two rows or can you have more that need to be filled in?

Comment: It's always fixed number of rows. Also, there can be more than two rows.

Comment: What should happen if the days are not consecutive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option based on this [enumerate/unstack/stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67063498/13138364) method which handles arbitrary dates:

```py
rows = 4
(df.assign(enum=df.groupby('Date').cumcount())
   .set_index(['enum', 'Date'])
   .unstack('Date')
   .reindex(range(rows + 1))
   .stack('Date', dropna=False)
   .sort_index(level='Date')
   .reset_index('Date')
   .interpolate()
   .reset_index(drop=True)
).iloc[:-rows]
```

Input:

```
         Date  Confirmed Cases
0  2020-12-27              100
1  2020-12-28             1000
2  2020-12-29             5000
```

Output:

```
         Date  Confirmed Cases
0  2020-12-27            100.0
1  2020-12-27            280.0
2  2020-12-27            460.0
3  2020-12-27            640.0
4  2020-12-27            820.0
5  2020-12-28           1000.0
6  2020-12-28           1800.0
7  2020-12-28           2600.0
8  2020-12-28           3400.0
9  2020-12-28           4200.0
10 2020-12-29           5000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
rows=4
df1 = pd.concat([df.iloc[0:1], pd.DataFrame([[np.nan]*df.shape[1]]*rows, columns=df.columns), df.iloc[-1:]], ignore_index=True)
df1['Confirmed_Cases'] = df1['Confirmed_Cases'].interpolate()
df1['Date'] = df1['Date'].ffill()
```

**Output**

```
         Date  Confirmed_Cases
0  2020-12-27            100.0
1  2020-12-27            280.0
2  2020-12-27            460.0
3  2020-12-27            640.0
4  2020-12-27            820.0
5  2020-12-28           1000.0
```

You will need to `import numpy as np` for this.

Comment: What if I want to use it for more than two rows? I could loop it, but is there any more efficient way?

Comment: if you have more than two rows you can concat based on the index of your rows.

Comment: for example if you want to insert 4 rows in an table of an arbitrary number of rows at index 1:

`df = pd.concat([df.iloc[0:1], pd.DataFrame([[np.nan]*df.shape[1]]*rows, columns=df.columns), df.iloc[1:]], ignore_index=True)`, then
`df['Confirmed Cases'] = df['Confirmed Cases'].interpolate()`, and then 
`df['Date'] = df['Date'].ffill()`